# What process reads blocks to the buffer cache?

Tags: oracle, architecture

**DBWR** processes write dirty blocks from the buffer cache to the data files. 
Documentation tells that blocks are read to the buffer cache before they are formed into result set . But "**who**" does that reading? How do you call that process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [overview of server processes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#CNCPT1248):

> Oracle Database creates server processes to handle the requests of client processes connected to the instance. A client process always communicates with a database through a separate server process.
>
> Server processes created on behalf of a database application can perform one or more of the following tasks:
>
> - Parse and run SQL statements issued through the application, including creating and executing the query plan (see "Stages of SQL Processing")
> - Execute PL/SQL code
> - Read data blocks from data files into the database buffer cache (the DBWn background process has the task of writing modified blocks back to disk)
> - Return results in such a way that the application can process the information

So each dedicated or shared server process populates the buffer cache as it reads data from the disk.

Writing out the modified blocks is done through a common DBWR background process so it can be asynchronous, and can also combine changes from multiple sessions. You don't generally want your application to wait for (slow) physical disk writes when it doesn't have to; it does have to wait for data to be read though, so there wouldn't be much benefit in making it a separate background process.

You don't explicitly call that process though, it's just handled behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer. I know you don't explicitly call (most) processes in oracle, but I once failed an interview on a question like this one...

Answer (score 1):

Every client's session process reads datafiles.

Therefore the formula for OS kernel limit for number of opened files contains:

```
#processes * #datafiles
```

You can also easily check it by using `lsof` on Linux.